# How to add buttons dynamically with a MessagingCenter in Xamarin.Forms MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, messaging

I want to add buttons in a dynamic view, for example in some cases I will add 2 buttons and in certain opportunities I will add 4 buttons, but I want to generalize all this logic in a view to which I only pass parameters such as view title, number of buttons, etc ... so that then the user is deployed in the following way ...

[image: 2 buttons] [image: 4 buttons]

to do so, discard certain implementations:

1.- Use a , since this generates a dead space if the list comes with few elements
2.- Use the  control since this does not exist for Android-iOS

When using MVVM as an architectural pattern, it is difficult for me to pass parameters to the CodeBehind, for the previous use a MessagingCenter in which I pass a string list which I finally go through and I am adding buttons, but this is not working

you have the following view with a corresponding x: Name...

View.xaml:

```
<Label
         Text="{Binding Titulo}"
         HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
</Label>

<StackLayout 
          x:Name="EntriesStackLayout">

</StackLayout>
```

is in the ViewModel of the View where I pass the list through MessagingCenter

ViewModel.cs:

```
#region Constructor
public OptionsPopUpViewModel(string title, List<string> opciones)
{         
    Titulo = title;
    opcionesMensaje = opciones;

    MessagingCenter.Send((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "Opciones", opcionesMensaje);
}
#endregion
```

Then in the Code behind of the View I receive in the method OnAppearing () and I create the button in the View

View.xaml.cs:

```
 public OptionsPopUpView()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
 }

  protected override void OnAppearing()
  {
      base.OnAppearing();

      MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, List<string>>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "Opciones", (s, opcionesMensaje) =>
      {
          foreach (var item in opcionesMensaje)
          {
              Button boton = new Button();

               EntriesStackLayout.Children.Add(boton);
          }

      });
 }

 protected override void OnDisappearing()
 {
      base.OnDisappearing();
      MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<App, List<string>>(this, "Opciones");
 }
```

Expected behavior: Adding buttons depending on the number of items in the list

Behavior obtained: when tracking the code, the first one does not execute the OnAppering () method when I run for the second time it enters the method and it executes correctly, but it is not adding the buttons

Why am I getting this behavior?
because my code is not able to add the buttons if I am receiving the list in the MessagingCenter?

[image: MessagingCenter]

What am I doing wrong?
any help for me?

I hope this question helps those who are with the same problem

regards!

Comment: I have seen this question before as well, Why are you posting same question multiple times?

Comment: a) add some text to your buttons, b) be sure that you are doing UI updates on the main thread, and c) be sure that you are subscribing to a Message BEFORE you send it

Comment: In what way do you make sure that you are subscribing to me before sending it? @Jason

Comment: you are subscribing in OnAppearing, but sending in the constructor of the VM.  If the VM is created before the View appears then the timing will not work.  How you fix this depends on the design of your app - but subscribing in the page constructor might be a good start

Comment: Regrettably I have tried that way of subscribing without success. :( @Jason

Comment: are you sure the code block INSIDE of the Subscribe() method is not being called?

Comment: *TL;DR* but I think you need to set `VerticalOptions = "StartAndExpand"` for `EntriesStackLayout` since you have not set this, its not expanding even though buttons are added I believe.